# Admin user lacks admin permissions after hack and can't reinstate

Tags: admin, permissions, hacks, hacked

My site (4.5.3 on Apache/Linux) was hacked, I suspect something like the one [described here](http://mventory.com/articles/hardening-wordpress-installation/). As best I can tell I've removed or at least disabled the hack, however admin users aren't able to perform actions like updating WordPress, adding plugins, etc.

So far, I have tried:

1. Editing the existing admin user's permissions via phpMyAdmin.
2. Adding a completely new admin user via phpMyAdmin.
3. Overwriting core WP files with those from a fresh download (of the same version currently installed).
4. Disabled (and then completely removed) all plugins.

All to no avail. Any thoughts on what I can try next?

Comment: Make sure that your files have the correct permissions. i.e. they belong to the system user apache runs under. possibly `www-data`

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I wasn't as thorough as I thought in removing vestiges of the hack. Found some more obfuscated PHP in template files, along with some `.php` files I didn't have permissions for that shouldn't have been there.

Removed all that, and admin functionality is back to normal.